# Is there a KDE theme that uses classic checkboxes ( ☒ or ☑ )?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, checkbox

The ones of the *Kubuntu* theme:

[image]

are not too convenient if you are used to ☒ or ☑ for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open KDE System Settings and then visit Appearance, Application Style to see the following (screenshot from Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS):

> [image: Kubuntu]

So ☑ are presented in

- Fusion
- MS Windows 9x
- Oxygen

styles.

Comment: Is it possible to make Breeze use  ☑, while keeping everything else the same?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I don't think so, but you can install [qtcurve](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qtcurve&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) which will appear as a new application style, it offers tons of options.

Comment: Thanks! _MS Windows 9x_ is much more classic than I expected to exist. :)